# Zend Framework 1.12 - AppendStylesheet makes link to CSS file twice

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller

I am doing the examples in the book "Zend Framework - A Beginner's Guide". I am almost done but I have found a few weird issues. One of them is in my admin.phtml layout file. I have this code:

```
<?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/master.css'); ?>
```

When I load the page I see it displays the master.css link twice:

```
<link href="/square2/public/css/master.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
<link href="/square2/public/css/master.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

When I comment out the appendStyleSheet() function, as expected, nothing shows up. Any reason why this function is doing it twice when I only make the call once?

Addendum: As a test I did two appendStyleSheet functions and in the resulting page I see the CSS file three times, apparently twice for the first call and once for the second. Any clues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just echo headLink

```
<?php $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/master.css'); ?>
<?= $this->headLink(); ?>
```

Comment: This helped me figure it out. The code was echoing another appendstylesheet for a different css file, hence echoing the first css file twice, and that is where the problem was. I will write the author to tell him he made an error.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by using setStylesheet() instead:

```
<?php $this->headLink()->setStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/master.css'); ?>
```

As explained by Joel Joel Binks, the first call to appendStylesheet() appends the stylesheet and returns it. The second call returns any previously appended stylesheets plus the second stylesheet hence the first stylesheet will appear twice.